# Setting default perspective in Eclipse for plugin development

Tags: eclipse, view, target, platform, perspective

I'm creating some plugins for Eclipse, and I have selected as **Target Platform** another Eclipse installation, when I run the plugin it launch the Eclipse instance successfully but it always is opened on the **Resources** perspective, anyone knows how to specify the default for example **Java EE** perspective when launching another instance of Eclipse selected as target platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default perspective in the `plugin_customization.ini` file in the target platform `plugins/org.eclipse.sdk` (or it might be `plugins/org.eclipse.platform` depending on your launch configuration). Add the line:

```
org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=perspective id
```

Comment: Is possible that another file is overriding this configuration? Because I modified both files in org.eclipse.sdk and org.eclipse.platform to use the Java EE perspective (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui), but still is opening the Resources perspective

Comment: I think once the workspace has been created the perspective is remembered you may need to clear the workspace or try a new one.

Comment: Hello, How can I know the `perspective id` for the `c/c++ perspective`?