# How to make sure that the rcp application always open in specific perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working in an rcp application which I want to always open in specific perspective .I tried mentioning `-perspective id` but that is not solving my issue.And suppose my workbench is closed in perspective B then when user open it for second time it is always opening from B.
Any clue on this will  help.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your default perspective in `Windows > Preferences > General > Perspectives` preference page.

Can also be done through `config.ini` file [Check here](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/11/02/eclipse-setting-the-default-perspective-via-config-ini/).

Using `plugin_customization.ini` file. Check here [Setting default perspective in Eclipse for plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868050/setting-default-perspective-in-eclipse-for-plugin-development)